# C: linking a different C file in a Driver program?

Tags: c, header, linker

Well,I am making a program that can Implement every form of Data structure i.e,**linked list**,**queue**,**stack**. And created separate file for each ,Now I want to use each of the separate file in a single driver program.
I've linked the file as:

```
#include"filename.c"
```

But an error shows up *no such file or directory*. And yeah, any other thing which i need to *implement* to use the *functions* of included files in the driver program .

Comment: first of all, you *can* include *implementation files* (`*.c`), but it normally makes no sense. That's what header files (`*.h`) are for, only describing the *interface*. Apart from that, getting *no such file or directory* means that wherever your `filename.c` is, it's not in the search path your preprocessor uses (typically including the path of whatever main file you're compiling).

Comment: Include "filename.h" and make sure it is present in the same directory in which your driver program is present. Otherwise use -I<path_to_include_file> during compilation

Comment: oh and ... "`#include`ing" a file is **not** linking.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Well that's the question I asked "how to `link` a C file to another.`And yeah, any other thing which i need to implement to use the functions of included files in the driver program .` Here I am asking U that only...!!!

Comment: @FelixPalmen can you make yourself clear on your 1st comment ??

Answer (score -1):

You don't include `.c` files, rather `.h` files.

Assuming you have folder containing your `main.c` file and a `datastructs.c` file, create a `datastructs.h` file that contains all the function declarations.

`datastructs.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "datastructs.h"

void hello() {
    printf("hello, world!\n");
}
```

`datastructs.h`

```
void hello();
```

Now, in the `main.c` - the C file containing the `main` function - include the `datastructs.h` file and invoke all the functions you want:

```
#include "datastructs.h"

void main() {
    hello();
}
```

Make sure to compile every source you're using, it'll make sure to link everything correctly:

```
gcc datastructs.c main.c -o main
```

---

This is a very basic approach, there are more out there - which probably are even better than this - but it will get the job done.

Make sure to check out how `Makefile` and `make` works, this way you can deal with this kind of tasks better.

Comment: First you CAN include .c files if you want to so rephrase the first sentence to expand on that. Second, don't use a filename like "datastructs.h" because that confuses the reader into assuming that only data structures end up in a separate file (change that to foo.h to show that this is arbitrary choice) third perhaps you can explain how object files are generated using c ... fourth don't assume that the user is using gcc.